# Access and VBA: Add date to all values of one column during import

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import

I have problems with adding a date to column while importing an excel file. My set up is as follows:

I have an AccessDB where I want to import an Excel report on a daily basis. I have a form where I can browse for the report and import it by clicking a second button to a table called "tblImport". This works just fine.

I have now an empty column in the "tblImport" where I want to add the date of the report for every row that is not Null. The empty column is already defined as a date column. The date is at the end of the filename "YYYYMMDD.xlsx".
The perfect solution would be to get the date directly from the filename and add it to the column. But it would be also fine to add an input box or an field in the form where I have to add the date.

However, every solution I found did not work with my code.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

The code for the form is as follows:

```
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click()
    Dim diag As Office.FileDialog
    Dim item As Variant
    
    Set diag = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    diag.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diag.Title = "Please select an Excel Spreadsheet"
    diag.Filters.Clear
    diag.Filters.Add "Excel Spreadsheets", "*.xls, *.xlsx"
    
    If diag.Show Then
        For Each item In diag.SelectedItems
            Me.txtFileName = item
        Next
    End If
    

End Sub

Private Sub btnImportSpreadsheet_Click()
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    
    If Nz(Me.txtFileName, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a file!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If FSO.FileExists(Me.txtFileName) Then
        ExcelImport.ImportExcelSpreadsheet Me.txtFileName, FSO.GetFileName(Me.txtFileName)
    Else
        MsgBox "File not found!"
    End If
End Sub
```

The import function looks as follows:

```
Public Sub ImportExcelSpreadsheet(fileName As String, tableName As String)

On Error GoTo BadFormat
    DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM tblImport;")
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tblImport", fileName, True, "A1:F4"
    MsgBox "Import successful!"
    Exit Sub
    
BadFormat:
    MsgBox "The file you tried to import was not an Excel spreadsheet."

End Sub
´´´
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a function to get the date.  This is based on the date being in the same place in the format mentioned.  You can elaborate on this code, probably best to add some error checking in the date conversion function also.  It's still early here so not fully tested :)

```
Public Sub ImportExcelSpreadsheet(fileName As String, tableName As String)

On Error GoTo BadFormat
    docmd.runsql ("DELETE * FROM tblImport;")
    docmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tblImport", fileName, True, "A1:F4"
    '   ***
    docmd.runsql ("Update tblImport set DateImported='" & GetDateFromFileName(fileName) & "'")
    '   ***
    MsgBox "Import successful!"
    Exit Sub
    
BadFormat:
    MsgBox "The file you tried to import was not an Excel spreadsheet."

End Sub
```

and

```
Function GetDateFromFileName(strInputFileName As String) As Date

Dim strDatePart As String
Dim intFinalDot As Integer

intFinalDot = InStrRev(strInputFileName, ".")
strDatePart = Mid(strInputFileName, intFinalDot - 8, 8)

GetDateFromFileName = DateSerial(Mid(strDatePart, 1, 4), Mid(strDatePart, 5, 2), Mid(strDatePart, 7, 2))

End Function
```